# Trouble understanding A* pathfinding algorithm pseudocode on wikipedia

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode, path-finding

The pseudocode for the [A* algortihm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) on wikipedia semms to not be right, but i somebody smarter than me probably made it, so i doubt that is true.
Im having trouble understanding how:

```
 if tentative_gScore < gScore[neighbor]
```

can ever be true. I'll try to prove it here (also, current starts with being the start node, because it is the only thing in openSet at first):

```
tentative_gScore = distance(start, current) + distance(current, neighbor)
```

Because current is start, distance(start, current) is 0. therefore tentative_gScore is just:

```
tentative_gScore = distance(current, neighbor)
```

and if we replace current with start, and compare the two gScore's:

```
tentative_gScore = distance(start, neighbor)
gScore[neighbor] = distance(start neighbor)
```

I'm really having trouble seeing what i am misunderstanding, or is the pseudocode just wrong? afterall it is from wikipedia, and everyone can edit there.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that `gScore[neighbor]` is the best distance recorded so far to `neighbor`.  But we have not yet recorded the possibility of passing through `current`.  And so we may discover an improvement.

This is dramatically demonstrated at the start when `gScore` is given a default value of `Infinity`. That records the fact that we have NO routes to anything except `start`.  And makes it really easy to find improvements!

The one important guarantee that the algorithm depends on is that, by the time that we actually make a node `current`, we have discovered the best possible route to it. But until that point we can continue to improve distances.